# Trying to understand BLE UUIDs and handles (with bluetoothctl example)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32, bluez, bluetooth-gatt

As far as I understand, in BLE, UUIDs are universal IDs that serve to uniquely identify a BLE attribute. They can be 2, 4 or 128 bytes. When they are 2 or 4, the remaining bits until 128 are filled with a standard BLE base UUID: `0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`. **Is this correct?**

Having UUIDs, **why are handles needed?** From what I have seen in my example, they are displayed as part of the attribute 'identifier', e.g.

```
# bluetoothctl capture

Primary Service (Handle 0x0920)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0028
    000000ff-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Unknown
```

According to the logs I'm printing (which I will show below), the handle is `28`. **Is this correct? If so, what is the meaning of that 'Handle 0x0920'?**

I have implemented a GATT server example in an ESP32 board. For now, I'm printing some logs to verify that the numbers I see (UUIDs, handles...) match those I see when connecting with `bluetoothctl`. Here are the logs:

```
I (1009) ESP32-DHT11: Service (inst. ID 0, uuid ff) created
I (1009) ESP32-DHT11: Service (inst. = 0, uuid = ff) started --> handle = 28
I (1009) ESP32-DHT11: Charac. (uuid ff01) added to service ff
I (1019) ESP32-DHT11: Charac. ff01 --> handle = 2a
I (1019) ESP32-DHT11: Descriptor (uuid 2902) added to service ff
I (1029) ESP32-DHT11: Charac. descr. 2902 --> handle = 2b
I (1029) ESP32-DHT11: Adv. parmeters set successfully
```

And here is the complete `bluetoothctl` capture:

```
Primary Service (Handle 0x0009)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0001
    00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Generic Attribute Profile
Characteristic (Handle 0xae24)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0001/char0002
    00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Service Changed
Descriptor (Handle 0x0015)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0001/char0002/desc0004
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration


Primary Service (Handle 0x0920)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0028
    000000ff-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Unknown
Characteristic (Handle 0x6c84)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0028/char0029
    0000ff01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Unknown
Descriptor (Handle 0x0015)
    /org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0028/char0029/desc002b
    00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
    Client Characteristic Configuration
```

I believe the first three attributes belong to the GAP layer and therefore can be ignored. Let's focus in the 3 next. As you can see, the UUIDs in my logs match those in the `bluetoothctl` capture. If we consider handles the last part of the attributes identifiers, all of them match save one (`/org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0028/char0029` --> 0x29, which should be 0x2a according to my logs) **Why does this happen?**

**What are exactly the path-like 'identifiers'?** (e.g. `/org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0028/char0029`)

## Code

### The source code for this is quite long, so I attach it here at the end:
main.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"
#include "freertos/event_groups.h"

#include "nvs_flash.h"
#include "nvs.h"

#include "esp_system.h"
#include "esp_log.h"

#include "esp_bt.h"
#include "esp_bt_defs.h"
#include "esp_bt_main.h"
#include "esp_gap_ble_api.h"
#include "esp_gatts_api.h"
#include "esp_gatt_common_api.h"

#include "sdkconfig.h"
#include "app.h"

#define SENSOR_NAME "ESP32-DHT11"
#define TAG SENSOR_NAME

#define ARG_UNUSED(arg) ((void)arg)

static int16_t temp, hum;

static esp_attr_value_t sensor_data = {
    .attr_max_len = (uint16_t)sizeof(temp),
    .attr_len = (uint16_t)sizeof(temp),
    .attr_value = (uint8_t*)(&temp),
};

static void gap_handler(esp_gap_ble_cb_event_t event,
                        esp_ble_gap_cb_param_t* param)
{
    switch (event) {
    case ESP_GAP_BLE_ADV_DATA_SET_COMPLETE_EVT:
        esp_ble_gap_start_advertising(&adv_params);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

// TODO service_def is global and opaque.

static uint32_t short_uuid(esp_bt_uuid_t uuid)
{
    switch (uuid.len) {
        case 2:
            return uuid.uuid.uuid16;
        case 4:
            return uuid.uuid.uuid32;
        default:
            return (uint32_t)-1;
    }
}

/**
 * @brief Handle for the event REG. Triggered when an app. (a.k.a. profile) is
 * registered.
 *
 */
static esp_err_t gatts_register_evt_handler(esp_gatts_cb_event_t event,
                                            esp_gatt_if_t gatts_if,
                                            esp_ble_gatts_cb_param_t* param)
{
    esp_err_t rc = esp_ble_gatts_create_service(gatts_if,
                                                &service_def.service_id,
                                                GATT_HANDLE_COUNT);
    if (rc != ESP_OK) {
        return rc;
    }

    ESP_LOGI(TAG,
             "Service (inst. ID %x, uuid %x) created",
             service_def.service_id.id.inst_id,
             short_uuid(service_def.service_id.id.uuid));

    return rc;
}

/**
 * @brief Handle for the event CREATE (triggered after creating a GATTS
 * service). Stores the handle of the previously created service, starts it and
 * adds a characteristic to it.
 *
 */
static esp_err_t gatts_create_evt_handler(esp_gatts_cb_event_t event,
                                          esp_gatt_if_t gatts_if,
                                          esp_ble_gatts_cb_param_t* param)
{
    ARG_UNUSED(event);
    ARG_UNUSED(gatts_if);

    service_def.service_handle = param->create.service_handle;

    esp_err_t rc = esp_ble_gatts_start_service(service_def.service_handle);
    if (rc != ESP_OK) {
        return rc;
    }

    ESP_LOGI(TAG,
             "Service (inst. = %x, uuid = %x) started --> handle = %x",
             service_def.service_id.id.inst_id,
             short_uuid(service_def.service_id.id.uuid),
             service_def.service_handle);

    rc = esp_ble_gatts_add_char(service_def.service_handle,
                                &service_def.char_uuid,
                                ESP_GATT_PERM_READ | ESP_GATT_PERM_WRITE,
                                ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_READ
                                    | ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_NOTIFY,
                                &sensor_data,
                                NULL);
    if (rc != ESP_OK) {
        return rc;
    }

    ESP_LOGI(TAG,
            "Charac. (uuid %x) added to service %x",
            short_uuid(service_def.char_uuid),
            short_uuid(service_def.service_id.id.uuid));

    return rc;
}

/**
 * @brief Handles the event ADD_CHAR, which is triggered after a characteristic
 * has been added successfully. When a charac. is added, its handle is generated
 * (at runtime). This function gets it and stores it. Also, it adds a charac.
 * descriptor to the service.
 *
 */
static esp_err_t gatts_add_char_evt_handler(esp_gatts_cb_event_t event,
                                            esp_gatt_if_t gatts_if,
                                            esp_ble_gatts_cb_param_t* param)
{
    ARG_UNUSED(event);
    ARG_UNUSED(gatts_if);

    service_def.char_handle = param->add_char.attr_handle;

    ESP_LOGI(TAG,
             "Charac. %x --> handle = %x",
             short_uuid(service_def.char_uuid),
             service_def.char_handle);

    esp_err_t rc = esp_ble_gatts_add_char_descr(service_def.service_handle,
                                                &service_def.descr_uuid,
                                                ESP_GATT_PERM_READ
                                                    | ESP_GATT_PERM_WRITE,
                                                NULL,
                                                NULL);
    if (rc != ESP_OK) {
        return rc;
    }

    ESP_LOGI(TAG,
            "Descriptor (uuid %x) added to service %x",
            short_uuid(service_def.descr_uuid),
            short_uuid(service_def.service_id.id.uuid));

    return rc;
}

/**
 * @brief Handles the event ADD_CHAR, which is triggered after a descriptor
 * has been added successfully. It gets and stores such descriptor handle and
 * overrides the default advertising data.
 *
 */
static esp_err_t gatts_add_char_descr_evt_handler(
    esp_gatts_cb_event_t event,
    esp_gatt_if_t gatts_if,
    esp_ble_gatts_cb_param_t* param)
{
    ARG_UNUSED(event);
    ARG_UNUSED(gatts_if);

    service_def.descr_handle = param->add_char_descr.attr_handle;

    ESP_LOGI(TAG,
             "Charac. descr. %x --> handle = %x",
             short_uuid(service_def.descr_uuid),
             service_def.descr_handle);

    esp_err_t rc = esp_ble_gap_config_adv_data(&adv_data);
    if (rc != ESP_OK) {
        return rc;
    }

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Adv. parmeters set successfully");

    return rc;
}

/**
 * @brief Handles the event CONNECT, which is triggered by a host connection.
 * Updates the current connection params. with those from the incoming
 * connection. Also, stores the incoming GATTS interface ID (which signals
 * which service is being read) and connection ID.
 *
 * @todo Does gatts_if actually designate the app./profile rather than the
 * service?
 *
 */
static esp_err_t gatts_connect_evt_handler(esp_gatts_cb_event_t event,
                                           esp_gatt_if_t gatts_if,
                                           esp_ble_gatts_cb_param_t* param)
{
    ARG_UNUSED(event);

    update_conn_params(param->connect.remote_bda);
    service_def.gatts_if = gatts_if;
    service_def.client_write_conn = param->write.conn_id;

    ESP_LOGI(TAG,
             "Host connected, GATTS if. ID = %x, conn. ID = %x",
             service_def.gatts_if,
             service_def.client_write_conn);

    return ESP_OK;
}

/**
 * @brief Handles the event READ, which is triggered by a host read.
 *
 */
static esp_err_t gatts_read_evt_handler(esp_gatts_cb_event_t event,
                                        esp_gatt_if_t gatts_if,
                                        esp_ble_gatts_cb_param_t* param)
{
    ARG_UNUSED(event);

    ESP_LOGI(TAG, "Read on %x detected", param->read.handle);

    esp_gatt_rsp_t rsp = {0};
    rsp.attr_value.handle = param->read.handle;
    rsp.attr_value.len = sensor_data.attr_len;
    memcpy(rsp.attr_value.value, sensor_data.attr_value, sensor_data.attr_len);

    return esp_ble_gatts_send_response(gatts_if,
                                       param->read.conn_id,
                                       param->read.trans_id,
                                       ESP_GATT_OK,
                                       &rsp);
}

/**
 * @brief GATT event handler.
 *
 * @see esp_ble_gatts_app_register
 */
static void gatt_handler(esp_gatts_cb_event_t event,
                         esp_gatt_if_t gatts_if,
                         esp_ble_gatts_cb_param_t* param)
{
    esp_err_t rc = ESP_OK;

    switch (event) {
    case ESP_GATTS_REG_EVT:
        rc = gatts_register_evt_handler(event, gatts_if, param);
        break;

    case ESP_GATTS_CREATE_EVT:
        rc = gatts_create_evt_handler(event, gatts_if, param);
        break;

    case ESP_GATTS_ADD_CHAR_EVT:
        rc = gatts_add_char_evt_handler(event, gatts_if, param);
        break;

    case ESP_GATTS_ADD_CHAR_DESCR_EVT:
        rc = gatts_add_char_descr_evt_handler(event, gatts_if, param);
        break;

    case ESP_GATTS_CONNECT_EVT: {
        rc = gatts_connect_evt_handler(event, gatts_if, param);
        break;
    }

    case ESP_GATTS_READ_EVT:
        rc = gatts_read_evt_handler(event, gatts_if, param);
        break;

    case ESP_GATTS_WRITE_EVT: {
        ESP_LOGI(TAG,
                 "ESP_GATTS_WRITE_EVT %x %x",
                 service_def.descr_handle,
                 param->write.handle);

        if (service_def.descr_handle == param->write.handle) {
            uint16_t descr_value =
                param->write.value[1] << 8 | param->write.value[0];

            if (descr_value != 0x0000) {
                ESP_LOGI(TAG, "notify enable");
                esp_ble_gatts_send_indicate(gatts_if,
                                            param->write.conn_id,
                                            service_def.char_handle,
                                            sensor_data.attr_len,
                                            sensor_data.attr_value,
                                            false);
            } else {
                ESP_LOGI(TAG, "notify disable");
            }
            esp_ble_gatts_send_response(gatts_if,
                                        param->write.conn_id,
                                        param->write.trans_id,
                                        ESP_GATT_OK,
                                        NULL);
        } else {
            esp_ble_gatts_send_response(gatts_if,
                                        param->write.conn_id,
                                        param->write.trans_id,
                                        ESP_GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMIT,
                                        NULL);
        }
        break;
    }

    case ESP_GATTS_DISCONNECT_EVT:
        service_def.gatts_if = 0;
        esp_ble_gap_start_advertising(&adv_params);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (rc != ESP_OK) {
        ESP_LOGE(TAG, "GATTS error %d", rc);
    }
}

static int16_t asd = 0;

static int dht_read_data(int16_t* hum, int16_t* temp)
{
    if (asd == 255) {
        asd = 0;
    } else {
        asd++;
    }
    *hum = asd;
    *temp = 2 * asd;
    return ESP_OK;
}

static void read_temp_task(void* arg)
{
    while (1) {
        vTaskDelay(2000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
        if (dht_read_data(&hum, &temp) == ESP_OK) {
            temp /= 10;
            if (service_def.gatts_if > 0) {
                esp_ble_gatts_send_indicate(service_def.gatts_if,
                                            service_def.client_write_conn,
                                            service_def.char_handle,
                                            sensor_data.attr_len,
                                            sensor_data.attr_value,
                                            false);
            }
        } else {
            ESP_LOGE(TAG, "DHT11 read failed");
        }
    }
}

void app_main(void)
{
    init_service_def();

    esp_err_t ret = nvs_flash_init();
    if (ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NO_FREE_PAGES
        || ret == ESP_ERR_NVS_NEW_VERSION_FOUND) {
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_erase());
        ESP_ERROR_CHECK(nvs_flash_init());
    }
    esp_bt_controller_mem_release(ESP_BT_MODE_CLASSIC_BT);

    esp_bt_controller_config_t bt_cfg = BT_CONTROLLER_INIT_CONFIG_DEFAULT();
    esp_bt_controller_init(&bt_cfg);
    esp_bt_controller_enable(ESP_BT_MODE_BLE);
    esp_bluedroid_init();
    esp_bluedroid_enable();

    esp_ble_gap_register_callback(gap_handler);
    esp_ble_gatts_register_callback(gatt_handler);
    esp_ble_gatts_app_register(0);

    xTaskCreate(read_temp_task,
                "temp",
                configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE * 3,
                NULL,
                5,
                NULL);
}
```

### app.c

```
#include "app.h"
#include <string.h>

static uint8_t adv_service_uuid128[32] = {
    0xfb,
    0x34,
    0x9b,
    0x5f,
    0x80,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x80,
    0x00,
    0x10,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0xFF,
    0x00,
    0x00,
    0x00,
};

esp_ble_adv_data_t adv_data = {
    .set_scan_rsp = false,
    .include_name = true,
    .include_txpower = false,
    .min_interval = 0x0006,
    .max_interval = 0x0010,
    .appearance = 0x00,
    .manufacturer_len = 0,
    .p_manufacturer_data = NULL,
    .service_data_len = 0,
    .p_service_data = NULL,
    .service_uuid_len = sizeof(adv_service_uuid128),
    .p_service_uuid = adv_service_uuid128,
    .flag = (ESP_BLE_ADV_FLAG_GEN_DISC | ESP_BLE_ADV_FLAG_BREDR_NOT_SPT),
};

esp_ble_adv_params_t adv_params = {
    .adv_int_min = 0x20,
    .adv_int_max = 0x40,
    .adv_type = ADV_TYPE_IND,
    .own_addr_type = BLE_ADDR_TYPE_PUBLIC,
    .channel_map = ADV_CHNL_ALL,
    .adv_filter_policy = ADV_FILTER_ALLOW_SCAN_ANY_CON_ANY,
};

service_info_t service_def;

void init_service_def(void)
{
    service_def.service_id.is_primary = true;
    service_def.service_id.id.inst_id = 0x00;
    service_def.service_id.id.uuid.len = ESP_UUID_LEN_16;
    service_def.service_id.id.uuid.uuid.uuid16 = GATT_SERVICE_UUID;

    service_def.char_uuid.len = ESP_UUID_LEN_16;
    service_def.char_uuid.uuid.uuid16 = GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID;

    service_def.descr_uuid.len = ESP_UUID_LEN_16;
    service_def.descr_uuid.uuid.uuid16 = ESP_GATT_UUID_CHAR_CLIENT_CONFIG;

    service_def.gatts_if = 0;
}

void update_conn_params(esp_bd_addr_t remote_bda)
{
    esp_ble_conn_update_params_t conn_params = {0};
    memcpy(conn_params.bda, remote_bda, sizeof(esp_bd_addr_t));
    conn_params.latency = 0;
    conn_params.max_int = 0x20;
    conn_params.min_int = 0x10;
    conn_params.timeout = 400;
    esp_ble_gap_update_conn_params(&conn_params);
}
```

### app.h

```
#ifndef gattex_app_h_
#define gattex_app_h_

#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include "esp_gap_ble_api.h"
#include "esp_gatts_api.h"

#define GATT_SERVICE_UUID 0x00FF
#define GATT_CHARACTERISTIC_UUID 0xFF01
#define GATT_HANDLE_COUNT 4

typedef struct
{
    uint16_t service_handle;
    esp_gatt_srvc_id_t service_id;
    uint16_t char_handle;
    esp_bt_uuid_t char_uuid;
    uint16_t descr_handle;
    esp_bt_uuid_t descr_uuid;
    esp_gatt_if_t gatts_if;
    uint16_t client_write_conn;

} service_info_t;

extern esp_ble_adv_data_t adv_data;
extern esp_ble_adv_params_t adv_params;
extern service_info_t service_def;

void init_service_def(void);
void update_conn_params(esp_bd_addr_t remote_bda);

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been investigating more and found specific answers to my questions, specially to those related to `bluetoothctl` in particular:

> When they are 2 or 4, the remaining bits until 128 are filled with a standard BLE base UUID: 0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb. Is this correct?

As explained by other people, the answer is yes.

> Having UUIDs, why are handles needed?

Other people answered this, but just to add some comments in case they help:

- UUID defines the type of the attribute, e.g. heart rate. This, most of the times, is registered in the SIG BLE database for UUIDs. That means that any device providing, for example, a heart rate, will use the heart rate's UUID. See [BLE assigned numbers](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/)
- Handles are the way a central device has to refer to a peripheral attribute in particular. E.g. a smartphone might be talking with 2 different smart watches, both of them providing the heart rate. Both watches will use the same UUID for this attribute, but the handle will (99% sure) be different. The handles could match, but it would be a mere chance.

Now, the `bluetoothctl` specific part:

> [...] (/org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0028/char0029 --> 0x29, which should be 0x2a according to my logs) Why does this happen?

It seems that `bluetoothctl` abstract out several attributes. In general, characteristics are sets of attributes in which one of them will contain the actual value, and many others will be meta-data for the characteristic, e.g. to describe its properties (notify, indicate etc.). This is what is happening here.

I have discovered this by using a lower level tool: `gatttool`. With it, I have been able to list all the attributes that describe the characteristic in question:

```
gatttool -b 0C:B8:15:F6:61:3E --char-desc 0x002a
handle = 0x0001, uuid = 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0002, uuid = 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0003, uuid = 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0004, uuid = 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0014, uuid = 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0015, uuid = 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0016, uuid = 00002a00-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0017, uuid = 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0018, uuid = 00002a01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0019, uuid = 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x001a, uuid = 00002aa6-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0028, uuid = 00002800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x0029, uuid = 00002803-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x002a, uuid = 0000ff01-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
handle = 0x002b, uuid = 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

As you can see, there is a big list of them. More interesting than that, both 0x2a and 0x29 handles are there. I have tried reading both:

```
[0C:B8:15:F6:61:3E][LE]> char-read-hnd 0x002a
Characteristic value/descriptor: 32 00
```

I can tell the above value is the actual charac. value (I know it because I have written the program that generates it, the code is above). So 0x2a is the handle of the attr. that contains the actual value of the characteristic in question.

Now, reading 0x29 gives:

```
[0C:B8:15:F6:61:3E][LE]> char-read-hnd 0x0029
Characteristic value/descriptor: 12 2a 00 01 ff
```

That value can be decoded by following this table, which describes the contents of *Characteristic declaration attributes*:

[image]

As you can see, the first byte is `0x12` which represents the flags of permitted operations (in this case: read,notify. See *Notes* below). The next 2 are the handle of the attribute it is describing: 0x002a (same handle as above. Notice that the endianness needs to be switched). The last 2 bytes are the UUID of the characteristic in question, that is, 0x01ff (which is an UUID invented by me, it's not in the SIG's registered UUIDs provided above). Again, this needs to switch the endianness.

> What are exactly the path-like 'identifiers'?

As explained by other people, this is not part of the BLE standard, it's a D-Bus thing.

In summary, the source of all this confusion comes from reading standard BLE documentation/books and the fact that `bluetoothctl` abstracts out a good part of this without providing documentation about what it is doing (I haven't found a single document explaining the data displayed by bluetoothctl at least)

### Notes

The characteristic properties is a bitfield whose bits, according to the ESP-IDF implementation, are:

```
/* definition of characteristic properties */
#define    ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_BROADCAST    (1 << 0)       /* 0x01 */    /* relate to BTA_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_BROADCAST in bta/bta_gatt_api.h */
#define    ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_READ         (1 << 1)       /* 0x02 */    /* relate to BTA_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_READ in bta/bta_gatt_api.h */
#define    ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_WRITE_NR     (1 << 2)       /* 0x04 */    /* relate to BTA_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_WRITE_NR in bta/bta_gatt_api.h */
#define    ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_WRITE        (1 << 3)       /* 0x08 */    /* relate to BTA_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_WRITE in bta/bta_gatt_api.h */
#define    ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_NOTIFY       (1 << 4)       /* 0x10 */    /* relate to BTA_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_NOTIFY in bta/bta_gatt_api.h */
#define    ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_INDICATE     (1 << 5)       /* 0x20 */    /* relate to BTA_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_INDICATE in bta/bta_gatt_api.h */
#define    ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_AUTH         (1 << 6)       /* 0x40 */    /* relate to BTA_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_AUTH in bta/bta_gatt_api.h */
#define    ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_EXT_PROP     (1 << 7)       /* 0x80 */    /* relate to BTA_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_EXT_PROP in bta/bta_gatt_api.h */
typedef uint8_t esp_gatt_char_prop_t;
```

As you can see in my code, this characteristic is

```
ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_READ | ESP_GATT_CHAR_PROP_BIT_NOTIFY
```

which is `((1 << 4) | (1 << 1)) == 0x12`.

Answer (score 1):

The LE attribute data is stored as a sequence of handles with data as in this example:

```
Handle

0001  UUID = 2800 (Primary service) Value = 1800 (UUID of the primary service)
   
   The attributes that belong to this primary service follow:
   
0002  UUID = 2803 (Characteristic info)  Value = Handle (0003) permissions and UUID of the following characteristic
0003  UUID = as in previous handle       Value = Value of the characteristic

0004  UUID = 2803 (Characteristic info)  Value = Handle (0005) permissions and UUID of the following characteristic
0005  UUID = as in previous handle       Value = Value of the characteristic

   Some characteristics are followed by a descriptor (e.g. notify enable)

0006  UUID = 2803 (Characteristic info)  Value = Handle (0007) permissions and UUID of the following characteristic
0007  UUID = as in previous handle       Value = Value of the characteristic 
0008  UUID = 2902 (Descriptor for notify enable) Value = 00 00 (notify off) or 00 01 (notify on)

   There might then be another primary service
   
0009  UUID = 2800 (Primary service) Value = 1801 (UUID of the primary service)   

   etc....
```

A client only needs the value handle (e.g. 0003 above) to read/write the characteristic. If it does not know the handle, it must read this database to find the handle from the UUID. It will read all the handles looking for UUID=2803 entries. A 2-byte UUID (e.g. 1801) may also appear as a 16-byte standard value with the 2 bytes at bytes 3/4:  00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB.
Normally, the client will read the database on connection and set up the dbus objects using the handles it finds. So the first characteristic in the example is a member of the primary service with handle 0001, and has an info handle of 0002, so it will appear as ..../service0001/char0002. It will read and write using handle 0003. The other handles listed first (like Characteristic (Handle 0xae24)) seem to invented by bluetoothctl for its own purposes and are unknown to the LE device, so confusion is created by two types of handle.

Answer (score 0):

The UUID (e.g. `00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb`) is the identifier of the GATT service/characteristic etc. This is used for identification GATT entries at a high level. There is a [reserved range](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/) for Bluetooth SIG adopted UUIDs. Outside of that range can be used for [Custom UUIDs](https://novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CA%20UUID%20is%20a%20universally,by%20their%2016%2Dbit%20aliases.)

The handle (e.g. `0x0009`) is the identifier for that specific entry in the local GATT database that gets built during service discovery. For example, there might a characteristic UUID used under multiple GATT services. However each database entry will have a different handle.

`bluetoothctl` communicates with the Bluetooth Daemon using [D-Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-Bus)  for inter process communication (IPC). For D-Bus there are three bits of information that are required: the D-Bus Service Name (`org.bluez`), the D-Bus interface (e.g. `org.bluez.GattService1`) and the D-Bus object path (e.g. `/org/bluez/hci0/dev_0C_B8_15_F6_61_3E/service0001`). The BlueZ API for GATT is documented at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/gatt-api.txt

Answer (score 0):

I think the other two answers do a good job of explaining what IS a handle. I want to answer your other two questions.

**(Re UUIDs) Is this correct?**

Yes. 2 byte (16 bit) UUIDs are just 128 bit UUIDs in disguise. They are assumed to have the default Bluetooth SIG UUID extension bits. This saves space in advertising packets.

**Why are handles needed?**

Handles are used by the stack. UUIDs are used by the application. They are intertwined which is why bluetoothctl can show them to you. However, as an application programmer, you don't need to know the handles. They are supposed to be hidden from you. You should think about the GATT server in terms of UUIDs, not handles. The stack (bluez) thinks about the GATT server in terms of handles.